# Rails Models "LoadError: Expected" and underscores (_) in name usage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, naming-conventions

On attempting to locate a model via rails console

```
>> f = DBFile.find_by_id(1)
>> NameError: uninitialized constant DBFile
>> D_B_File.all()
LoadError: Expected /home/thrive/rails_projects/tester/app/models/d_b_file.rb to define D_B_File
>> f = DBFile.find_by_id(1)
#<DBFile id: 1, file_name: "output-May-2010.csv">
```

Now when I rename the model d_b_file.rb  >> db_file.rb

```
>> f = DBFile.find_by_id(1)
#<DBFile id: 1, file_name: "output-May-2010.csv">
```

So what about the additional underscore in the original model name ...is preventing it from loading normally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the filename is directly related to the class name, since Rails relies on that to determine where it should look for the class.

So, `"DBFile".underscore` will give you `db_file`. So that's where Rails expects that class to be found.

Comment: So what Rails does is it looks at your `class DBFile ... end` and takes the classname and "underscorizes" it to find the file name it expects. In this case, `db_file.rb`. Anything else, it will complain.

Comment: AH .underscore is a rails method!